# Chart filling from LinkedList<String, int>

Tags: c#, wpf, charts

In my C#-WPF-application, I want to fill a WPF ColumnChart with the following:

```
private void LoadPieChartData()
{
    LinkedList<String> kostenstellen = rep.GetKostenstellen();
    foreach (String s in kostenstellen)
    {
        ((ColumnSeries)PieChart.Series[i]).ItemsSource =
            new KeyValuePair<string, double>[]{
            new KeyValuePair<string,double>(kostenstellen.ElementAt(i), i)
        };
        i++;
    }
}
```

here´s the xaml code:

```
                    <DVC:Chart HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="625,44,0,0" Name="PieChart" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="276" Width="256" > 
                        <DVC:Chart.Series>
                            <DVC:ColumnSeries ItemsSource="{Binding LoadPieChartData}" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}" />
                        </DVC:Chart.Series>
                    </DVC:Chart>
```

My problem is, that I get the following XamlParseException:

> 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'Finanz_WPF.MainWindow'
>   that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.

Isn´t it possible to iterate PieChart.Series? 
In which way can I manage that?

Answer (score 1):

A `DependencyProperty` is meant to point to a value, not to a method.

Either change your binding to point to a `Property` instead of a `Method`, or run your `LoadPieChartData()` method in the `Loaded` event of your `ColumnSeries`

Comment: Also, to add to Rachel answer, binding always works for public properties. So, make it a public property.. :)

Comment: The problem is, that I don´t want to bind it to a property.
I found out, that if I try to iterate Series, the WPF-object must exist.

Comment: @user896692 So run it in the `Loaded` event of your `ColumnSeries`. Just use `(ColumnSeries)sender` to get your ColumnSeries instead of `PieChart.Series[i]`

Comment: Thanks for that hint! But I still have a question, I neve worked with sender until today. How can I iterate my list now? Because sender[i], for sure, isn´t possible

Comment: @user896692 The method signature for the Loaded event of ColumnSeries should be `void ColumnSeries_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)` and the `sender` object will be your `ColumnSeries`. You just need to cast it to the correct type to use it

Comment: yes, I know the method head.. 
I need sender to be a (ColumnSeries), so I can write ((ColumnSeries)sender).ItemsSource = ... 
Sorry, but even then I don´t know how to solve my problem. I need a series for every entry in my list.